# C# reading json and output file only getting 1 record

Tags: c#, json, console

I've been trying complete an assignment I can't use a serialize. I've got the output they way it needs to be however I'm only getting 1 record instead of 100 with 150 fields. need some fresh eyes and advise from some more seasoned vets.

```
namespace ChadE_json
{
    class Program
    {
        //Output location
        static string outputFolder = @"..\..\Output";

        //Var
        static List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        static List<string> dataFile = new List<string>();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create DIR if not created
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
            loadLabels();
            dataFile.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            saveData();
        }

        private static void saveData()
        {
            using (StreamWriter outStream = new StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\Data.json"))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        //+1 to skip header
                        outStream.WriteLine("{\n" + "\"" + labels[i] + "\"" + ": " + "\"" + dataFile[i+1] + "\"" + ",");
                    }
                    else if (i == labels.Count -1)
                    {
                        outStream.WriteLine("\"" + labels[i] + "\"" + ": " + "\"" + dataFile[i+1] + "\"" + "\n\t}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outStream.WriteLine("\"" + labels[i] + "\"" + ": " + "\"" +  dataFile[i+1] + "\"" + ",");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void loadLabels()
        {
            using (StreamReader labelReader = new StreamReader(outputFolder + @"\DATA\DFieldsLayout.txt"))
            {
                while (labelReader.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    string line = labelReader.ReadLine();
                    labels.Add(line);
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    loadData1();

                }
            }
        }

        private static void loadData1()
        {
            using (StreamReader labelReader = new StreamReader(outputFolder + @"\DATA\DFile1.txt"))
            {
                while (labelReader.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    string line = labelReader.ReadLine();
                    string[] dataArray = line.Split('|');
                    dataFile.AddRange(dataArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT:
    {
"DUNS": "928338219",
"DUNS+4": "",
"CAGE CODE": "3HY83",
"DODAAC": "",
"SAM EXTRACT CODE": "A",
"PURPOSE OF REGISTRATION": "Z5",
"REGISTRATION DATE": "20030917",
"EXPIRATION DATE": "20160629",
"LAST UPDATE DATE": "20150630",
"ACTIVATION DATE": "20150630",
"LEGAL BUSINESS NAME": "FEDERAL HIGHWAY ADMINISTRATION",
"DBA NAME": "",
"COMPANY DIVISION": "OFFICE OF ACQUISITIION AND GRANTS MANAGEMENT",
"DIVISION NUMBER": "",
"SAM ADDRESS 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVE SE",
"SAM ADDRESS 2": "",
"SAM CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"SAM PROVINCE OR STATE": "DC",
"SAM ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"SAM ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"SAM COUNTRY CODE": "USA",
"SAM CONGRESSIONAL DISTRICT": "98",
"BUSINESS START DATE": "19720101",
"FISCAL YEAR END CLOSE DATE": "0930",
"CORPORATE URL": "",
"ENTITY STRUCTURE": "2A",
"STATE OF INCORPORATION": "",
"COUNTRY OF INCORPORATION": "",
"BUSINESS TYPE COUNTER": "0003",
"BUS TYPE": "2R~NG~VW",
"PRIMARY NAICS": "926120",
"NAICS CODE COUNTER": "0001",
"NAICS CODE": "926120N",
"PSC CODE COUNTER": "0000",
"PSC CODE": "",
"CREDIT CARD USAGE": "",
"CORRESPONDENCE FLAG": "",
"MAILING ADDRESS LINE 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE, SE",
"MAILING ADDRESS LINE 2": "ROOM E65-101",
"MAILING ADDRESS CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"MAILING ADDRESS ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"MAILING ADDRESS ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"MAILING ADDRESS COUNTRY": "USA",
"MAILING ADDRESS STATE OR PROVINCE": "DC",
"GOVT BUS POC FIRST NAME": "FRANK WALTOS",
"GOVT BUS POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"GOVT BUS POC LAST NAME": "WALTOS",
"GOVT BUS POC TITLE": "",
"GOVT BUS POC ST ADD 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE, SE",
"GOVT BUS POC ST ADD 2": "ROOM E65-312",
"GOVT BUS POC CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"GOVT BUS POC ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"GOVT BUS POC ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"GOVT BUS POC COUNTRY CODE": "USA",
"GOVT BUS POC STATE OR PROVINCE": "DC",
"GOVT BUS POC U.S. PHONE": "2023664205",
"GOVT BUS POC U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"GOVT BUS POC NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"GOVT BUS POC FAX U.S. ONLY": "2023663705",
"GOVT BUS POC EMAIL": "Frank.Waltos@dot.gov",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC FIRST NAME": "FRANK",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC LAST NAME": "WALTOS",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC TITLE": "",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC ST ADD 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC ST ADD 2": "ROOM E65-312",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC COUNTRY CODE": "USA",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC STATE OR PROVINCE": "DC",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC U.S. PHONE": "2023664205",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC FAX U.S. ONLY": "2023663705",
"ALT GOVT BUS POC EMAIL": "Frank.Waltos@dot.gov",
"PAST PERF POC POC FIRST NAME": "",
"PAST PERF POC POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"PAST PERF POC POC LAST NAME": "",
"PAST PERF POC POC TITLE": "",
"PAST PERF POC ST ADD 1": "",
"PAST PERF POC ST ADD 2": "",
"PAST PERF POC CITY": "",
"PAST PERF POC ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "",
"PAST PERF POC ZIP CODE +4": "",
"PAST PERF POC COUNTRY CODE": "",
"PAST PERF POC STATE OR PROVINCE": "",
"PAST PERF POC U.S. PHONE": "",
"PAST PERF POC U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"PAST PERF POC NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"PAST PERF POC FAX U.S. ONLY": "",
"PAST PERF POC EMAIL": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC FIRST NAME": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC LAST NAME": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC TITLE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC ST ADD 1": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC ST ADD 2": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC CITY": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC ZIP CODE +4": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC COUNTRY CODE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC STATE OR PROVINCE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC U.S. PHONE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC FAX U.S. ONLY": "",
"ALT PAST PERF POC EMAIL": "",
"ELEC BUS POC FIRST NAME": "FRANK",
"ELEC BUS POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"ELEC BUS POC LAST NAME": "WALTOS",
"ELEC BUS POC TITLE": "",
"ELEC BUS POC ST ADD 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE",
"ELEC BUS POC ST ADD 2": "ROOM E65-312",
"ELEC BUS POC CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"ELEC BUS POC ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"ELEC BUS POC ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"ELEC BUS POC COUNTRY CODE": "USA",
"ELEC BUS POC STATE OR PROVINCE": "DC",
"ELEC BUS POC U.S. PHONE": "2023664205",
"ELEC BUS POC U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"ELEC BUS POC NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"ELEC BUS POC FAX U.S. ONLY": "2023663705",
"ELEC BUS POC EMAIL": "Frank.Waltos@dot.gov",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS POC FIRST NAME": "JASON",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS POC MIDDLE INITIAL": "",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS POC LAST NAME": "JOHNSON",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS POC TITLE": "",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS ST ADD 1": "1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS ST ADD 2": "",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS CITY": "WASHINGTON",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS ZIP/POSTAL CODE": "20590",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS ZIP CODE +4": "0001",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS COUNTRY CODE": "USA",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS STATE OR PROVINCE": "DC",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS U.S. PHONE": "2023665880",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS U.S. PHONE EXT": "",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS NON-U.S. PHONE": "",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS FAX U.S. ONLY": "2023663705",
"ALT ELEC POC BUS EMAIL": "jason.johnson@dot.gov",
"NAICS EXCEPTION COUNTER": "0000",
"NAICS EXCEPTION STRING": "",
"DELINQUENT FEDERAL DEBT FLAG": "N",
"EXCLUSION STATUS FLAG": "",
"SBA BUSINESS TYPES COUNTER": "0000",
"SBA BUSINESS TYPES STRING": "",
"NO PUBLIC DISPLAY FLAG": "",
"DISASTER RESPONSE COUNTER": "0000",
"DISASTER RESPONSE STRING": "",
"END OF RECORD INDICATOR": "!end"
    }
```

Comment: Firstly: I'd strongly, strongly advise you to stop writing JSON by hand like this. Use Json.NET or a similar library. Next, what have you observed while stepping through your code in a debugger? Finally, I'd avoid using `Peek` like this - just call `ReadLine()` and check whether it's `null` or not.

Comment: Show us a sample of the input data.

Comment: As I said I can't use a serializer or 3rd party plugin. and I added the output to the bottom of the code, there should be 99 more { 150 entries} but I'm just getting the one.

Comment: If you don't give us a small sample of the input data, we can't help you. Also, you need to show us a small sample of what you want the output to look like. Your code and the brief explanation you provide *is not enough* information for us to deduce what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you have two files. The first is the labels for the fields in the record. For example, "DUNS" or "DBA NAME".

The second file contains the data records, one record per line. Fields are separated by `|` characters.

You want to output all of the records, with the labels.

There are several problems. First, in your `loadData1` method:

```
    private static void loadData1()
    {
        using (StreamReader labelReader = new StreamReader(outputFolder + @"\DATA\DFile1.txt"))
        {
            while (labelReader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                string line = labelReader.ReadLine();
                string[] dataArray = line.Split('|');
                dataFile.AddRange(dataArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

This loads the entire data file into the `dataFile` list. But it splits the fields, so each entry is an individual field rather than a complete record. This ends up making your job harder. You should just store the entire record, like this:

```
    private static void loadData1()
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(outputFolder + @"\DATA\DFile1.txt")
        {
            dataFile.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Notice how I used [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) to more succinctly read a file sequentially.

The second problem I see is that you're calling `loadData1` inside of `loadLabels()`. You're reading the entire data file multiple times, which is unnecessary. You should remove the call to `loadData1` from `loadLabels`, and add it to your `main`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create DIR if not created
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
        loadLabels();
        loadData1();
        dataFile.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        saveData();
    }
```

Now, in your `saveData()` method, you want to write a loop that iterates over the `dataFile`, and for each record output the individual fields. Like this:

```
    private static void saveData()
    {
        using (StreamWriter outStream = new StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\Data.json"))
        {
            // For each data record
            for (int i = 0; i < dataFile.Count; ++i)
            {
                // split the record into fields
                var dataArray = dataFile[i].Split(|);

                outStream.WriteLine("{\n"); // start of record

                // output each field
                for (var 0 = 1; j < dataArray.Length; ++j)
                {
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        outStream.WriteLine(","); // field separator
                    }
                    outStream.Write("\"" + labels[j] + "\"" + ": \"" dataArray[j+1] + "\"");
                }
                outStream.WriteLine();    // final field newline
                outStream.WriteLine("}"); // and end of record
            }
        }
    }
```

I streamlined your loop to eliminate the redundant line output code. The idea here is to output a record, but defer outputting the comma until the next iteration, if it occurs. Makes the code smaller and reduces the chances for error when change the output format: you only have to change one line rather than three.

I think with those changes, the code will do what you want.

Comment: first file had one label per line
second record is a file with records all mashed together but separated by | IE. BOF PUBLIC 00000000 20151206 0608661 0005321
928338219||3HY83||A|Z5|20030917|

Comment: this should work, just have to fix a "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'" in the loadData1

Comment: @ChadE: Problem with that line is it should be `dataFile.Add` rather than `dataFile.AddRange`. I've fixed it in my code.

Comment: thanks for the help and guidance Jim. getting some minor errors of variable out of bounds but, I should be able to solve them. much appreciation!

Comment: @ChadE: Happy to help out. If you found this answer useful, please upvote it. If it solved your problem, please select as the accepted answer.

Comment: Will do, thanks for guiding/showing me a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate loop to call loadData1() until all the data is read. The way you are doing it now, only reads one data field per label. Thus it does not read more than one row of data.

Comment: But `loadData1` reads the entire file. At least, that's how I read that `while` loop.